# How to set custom certificate for Node in Magento PWA?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, pwa-studio

I use remote staging server to test my PWA application which is under development and based on Magento 2.3 Venia theme. I see the Node instance generates devcert certificate automatically on application run. But it is not trusted by browsers of course. I have my own Lets encrypt certificate for staging domain and want to force using it for my application.

How can I do it? I found only instructions of how to specify custom cert files for Express.js app, but Magento 2 PWA studio is quite complex and I don't know where should I specify it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In packages/package-name/.env :

```
MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_SSL_KEY='path/to/file'

MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_SSL_CERT='path/to/file'
```

In packages/package-name/webpack.config.js :

```
        devServerConfig.provideSecureHost = {
            subdomain: validEnv.MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_SUBDOMAIN,
            exactDomain:
                validEnv.MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_EXACT_DOMAIN,
            addUniqueHash: !!validEnv.MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_ADD_UNIQUE_HASH,
            keyFile: validEnv.MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_SSL_KEY,
            certFile: validEnv.MAGENTO_BUILDPACK_SECURE_HOST_SSL_CERT
        };
```

In packages/pwa-buildpack/src/WebpackTools/PWADevServer.js :

```
    devServerConfig.https =
        hostConf.certFile && hostConf.keyFile
            ? {
                  key: readFileSync(hostConf.keyFile, 'utf-8'),
                  cert: readFileSync(hostConf.certFile, 'utf-8')
              }
            : ssl;
```

Answer (score 0):

It is wrong.
In the latest version, in package/package-name/.env file

There are 2 config, just put your key & cert absolute path there.

```
#### Custom HTTPS certificates #################################################
#
#   Absolute path to the custom HTTPS certificate key file.
#   - Default when not set: 
CUSTOM_HTTPS_KEY=
#
#   Absolute path to the custom HTTPS certificate cert file.
#   - Default when not set: 
CUSTOM_HTTPS_CERT=
```

Comment: Where is 'package-name' package located? https://github.com/magento/pwa-studio